# Parsing a text file Row after another row

Tags: vb.net

I have this text file that I need to parse and put the parsed data in the database

```
Name   Qty1          Qty2      Name   Qty1   Qty2
 ABC    1              2       
 BCD    2              3
 EFG    7              9         PQR    56    97
 DEF    3              18        RET    988   11
```

I have a table where I need to put the above data

The table structure is like this

Name, Qty1, Qty2,Col

so If I parse from left side then I can put the ABC,1,2, L in the table and if Parse from right side then I can put PQR, 56, 97, R in the same table.

My problem is how can I differentiate between left column and right columns. As soon as I start reading, I can read ABC,1,2 and then I don't know if there is a value in Right column and if I keep reading through my VB.net code then, I will start reading BCD,2,3 and at that point I don't know if BCD belongs to Right Column or left column so I am not sure whether I put L or R in the database. I am trying to parse this file in .net using substring and Indexof. This file is generated from the pdf document. below is the code to read the pdf document:

```
Public ReadOnly Property getParsedFile() As String
    Get
        Dim document As New PDFDocument(filePath)

        Dim parsedFile As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        For i As Integer = 0 To document.Pages.Count - 1
            parsedFile.Append(document.Pages(i).GetText())
        Next

        Return parsedFile.ToString()

    End Get

End Property
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

below is the answer

```
 Public Function ExtractTextFromPdf(path As String) As String
    Dim its As iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.ITextExtractionStrategy = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy()

    Using reader As New PdfReader(path)
        Dim str As New StringBuilder()

        For i As Integer = 1 To reader.NumberOfPages
            Dim thePage As String = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, its)
            Dim theLines As String() = thePage.Split(ControlChars.Lf)
            For Each theLine As String In theLines
                str.AppendLine(theLine)










            Next
        Next
        saveTextFileOnComputer(str.ToString())
        Return str.ToString()
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: how are you reading your file? try [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can parse each line separately.

Comment: This parsed file is just a string. I don't have this file saved anywhere so what I am doing is ParsedFile.Substring(0, ParsedFile.IndexOf("Name", 0)) and then go ahead by using IndexOf and substring. I am not sure if this is the right way. I can save this string in a file if that can solve my problem.

Comment: You need some sort of end-of-line otherwise you can't tell.

Comment: I can save this continuous string in a file. Is there any way, I can introduce end of line in the file.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it's in a file or not - you need a way to tell that a line ends. Maybe it's the format of  the first item on a line, maybe it's a special character at the end of the line (cr/lf :) )

Comment: It is just a string. I am not sure how can I resolve this problem. I really need the files to be parsed. There are around 100 files. I am not sure if I can put end of line in this file.

Comment: you can split the string by newline and get an array of lines. it will be easier to parse each line instead on it as a single string.

Comment: at what point or character or position should I split the string.

Comment: You could create a temp table in your database, use the build-in function to dumb the csv into that table and have a store proc that'll convert the data into your live table.

Comment: I am translating this file from a pdf document and this pdf document is spitting out the text file that I need to parse.

Comment: This is not a csv, it is a string or a text file

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to tell you how to parse without line breaks or a consistent pattern to determine where a line ends or starts. Is the character count of each 'line' the same?

Comment: No, the character count is not same.

Comment: Is there any way I can introduce line breaks while reading the file from pdf document.I edited my post with the code of how am I converting the pdf file to text document. I am using pdfMosiac dll to convert the pdf file to text file.

Comment: I solved it using another type of pdfParser. I posted my code above.

Comment: You should write up the solution as an answer. Also when you reply to people, you should notify them like @user3862503.